# Why Some portion of Camera image is outside its view bound?

Tags: ios, swift, camera, avfoundation

I've set up a UIView where camera will be shown. Everything works fine, but when I set the videoGravity of the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer to AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill, it seems that the some top & bottom parts which are outside of the camera view frame are also visible in the clicked photo.Please see the attached image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDErR.jpg)

I tried setting clipsToBounds = true but it didn't seem to solve the problem.

Here is my code..

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var previewView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var capturedImage: UIImageView!
var session: AVCaptureSession?
var stillImageOutput: AVCaptureStillImageOutput?
var videoPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.previewView.clipsToBounds = true
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    configureCamera()
}
func configureCamera(){
    session = AVCaptureSession()
    session!.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto
    let backCamera = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)
    var error: NSError?
    var input: AVCaptureDeviceInput!
    do {
        input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: backCamera)
    } catch let error1 as NSError {
        error = error1
        input = nil
        print(error!.localizedDescription)
    }
    if error == nil && session!.canAddInput(input) {
        session!.addInput(input)
        stillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
        stillImageOutput?.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecJPEG]
        if session!.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput) {
            session!.addOutput(stillImageOutput)
            videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: session)
            videoPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
            videoPreviewLayer!.connection?.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
            let rootLayer :CALayer = self.previewView.layer
            rootLayer.masksToBounds = true
            videoPreviewLayer?.frame = rootLayer.bounds
            videoPreviewLayer?.masksToBounds = true
            rootLayer.addSublayer((videoPreviewLayer)!)
            rootLayer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
            rootLayer.borderWidth = 2.0
            self.previewView.clipsToBounds = true
            session!.startRunning()
        }
     }
}
@IBAction func btnTakePhoto(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let videoConnection = stillImageOutput!.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)
    if(videoConnection != nil) {
        stillImageOutput?.captureStillImageAsynchronously(from: videoConnection, completionHandler: { (sampleBuffer, error) -> Void in
            if sampleBuffer != nil {
                let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(sampleBuffer)
                let dataProvider = CGDataProvider(data: imageData as! CFData)
                let cgImageRef = CGImage.init(jpegDataProviderSource: dataProvider!, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: true, intent: CGColorRenderingIntent.relativeColorimetric)

                let image = UIImage(cgImage: cgImageRef!, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.right)
                self.capturedImage.image = image
                self.session!.stopRunning()

            }
        })
    }
}
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    videoPreviewLayer!.frame = self.previewView.layer.bounds
    self.previewView.clipsToBounds = true

}
}
```

Please note that I don’t want to use any other videoGravity like AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect.Please someone help me. I am struggling very badly.

Comment: `ViewWillAppear` is too early to call `configureCamera` can you call it in `ViewDidAppear` and check. I think in ViewWillAppear your previewLayer's frame isnt finalized and you end up creating a camera with a `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer ` wrong dimension hence wrong image preview looks fine because you have clip to bounds. Just guessing try n lemme know

Comment: Same problem also in ViewDidAppear @SandeepBhandari

Comment: `AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill` will maintain aspect ratio and fill the layer, meaning content can go out of bounds. Since you don't want to use `AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect`, you basically need your layer's frame aspect ratio to match the aspect ratio of your input so that no portion of the image is outside of the bounds !

Comment: @Valérian can you please share some code?